# how to check for nuget "package management" in vsts?

Tags: c#, .net, git, nuget, azure-devops

My organization has projects set up in VSTS but I'm not sure if the VSTS instance is set up to host package feeds. Based on some basic googling, there appears to be a "Package Management" extension for this.  Is this the extension that I need to install to provide NuGet package capabilities via VSTS for my organization?:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.feed

Is there a way to identify the extensions which have been installed for a VSTS instance?  For example, is there a menu item that I can navigate to in VSTS which will display a list of installed extensions?  How can I identify if the "Package Management" extension has been installed for my organization's VSTS instance?  Are there any alternative extensions that might be configured for my organization's VSTS which would provide NuGet package hosting capabilities?

**UPDATE**

I'm trying to understand the pricing parameters for the "Package Management" VSTS extension:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.feed#pricing

"Package Management is included for Visual Studio Enterprise subscribers" but it looks like one of these subscriptions is massively expensive:

https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/pricing/

"Additionally, each VSTS account includes 5 free Package Management users and you can pay for more as needed using the pricing to the right."

Based on the line quoted above it sounds like we can install the extension and 5 users will get to use the package for free. If we have 20 developers then we'll need to pay $60/month for everyone to be able to use apps with internally hosted packages, right?

I guess that means that unless we purchase additional licenses, other users simply won't be able to use apps which use internally hosted NuGet packages, b/c they won't be able to pull down those packages, right?  Do you know if there's a hack or workaround for users without a Package Management license to be able to pull down internally hosted packages?  I.e. I'm not sure if Microsoft will allow this but make you go through a few manual steps or if it's simply not possible without purchasing additional licenses.

Comment: You're not going to get any help with finding ways to commit piracy or otherwise circumvent licensing requirements here. If you want more than 5 users, buy the licenses.

Comment: I wasn't looking to commit piracy lol.  some software vendors offer a free version with a subset of features along with a paid-for premium option.  their strategy is to hook you with the free software and then hope that the additional features will be enticing enough for you to pay for

Comment: And it's 100% free and functional for 5 users. There's your hook. It's also free for Visual Studio Enterprise subscribers, which your developers may already be.

Comment: You could run a Proget server on Azure IaaS, the price per month will be higher than $40. You could get a private MyGet account at $795/yr.  or you could have a CI build drop the nuget package in a file share and suffer the lower performance for free.

Comment: And while there may be a few tricks I could think of, @DanielMann is right. The product is pretty competitively priced. You're aleady getting so much stuff for so little money with VSTS, they need to earn money somhow to keep improving the product.

Comment: Do you know if that's 5 concurrent users or do 5 specific users need to be registered?

Comment: Licenses are assigned per-user. VS Enterprise subscribers don't need an additional license.

Comment: "or you could have a CI build drop the nuget package in a file share"....are there any downsides to this approach besides performance?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to install the Package Management extension to allow NuGet package hosting.

You can see installed/requested extensions under the "Manage Extensions" view, which appears if you hover your mouse over the shopping bag icon on the right of the toolbar, near your user account. You should be able to request extension installation and see the status of requests even if you aren't an administrative user. However, only administrators can approve the installation of extensions.

[image]

Comment: Hehe you beat me to it, but I have more screenshots ;).

Comment: so is the "package management" extension free or is there a free version?

Comment: @user9393635 Look at the documentation. The extension itself is free, it's licensed per user. The first 5 users are free, beyond that you have to pay a per-user monthly fee. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.feed#pricing

Comment: thanks @DanielMann I added some questions specific to the extension under a new "UPDATE" section at the bottom of my original post

Answer (score 0):

It shoudl show up in the account level Setting\Extensions panel:

[image]

It can also be found under the "Manage Extensions" link in the SHoppign bag (lock-like) icon in the upper right corner.

[image]

When installed correctly (and you have the right license assigned in the users hub:

[image]

This means that, unless your users already have a Visual Studio Enterprise license (some Microsoft Partner Programs provide these for free), you will need to pay for each user above the free licenses that you get with Visualstudio.com. The price per user isn't fixed, depending on the number of users the price may vary a little, the pricing calculator will tell you exactly what the price per month will be. [For 20 developers it currently shows $40 per month in total.](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.feed#pricing)

It should show up in the Build & Release hub:

[image]

Comment: thanks @jessehouwing  I added some questions specific to the extension under a new "UPDATE" section at the bottom of my original post